# animation for drag and drop JLabel

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

I have ask alot of question about drag and drop for JLabel , but im learning from them ,im trying to drag and drop JLabel with image icon inside it , i want to be able to make a copy from it and drag it while user can see the image moving with the mouse and drop it in another JLabel , also i want to move it from one JPanel to another,how i can do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle, you need the `java.awt.dnd` package.

Get a `DragSource`, associate it with your source JLabel. Create a DropTarget, associate it with your target JLabel.
Add the right listeners (DropTargetListener, DragSourceListener), and react on the method calls appropriately.

Okay, seriously: Read [the tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html), try to implement it, and come back if you have more concrete problems.

Comment: i know how to use the drag and drop , but i want to make animation for the movements , i want user to see the dragged image moves with the mouse

Comment: It would help if you show what you already have - it is easier for us to simply add something there than to do everything from scratch.